Composition of the norm with an absolutely continuous function is absolutely continuous
Let $f:[a,b]\to \mathbb{R}^n$ be an absolutely continuous function. The $g:[a,b]\to \mathbb{R}, \ g(x):=|f(x)|,$ is the composition of an absolutely continuous and of a Lipschitz function. Hence, $g$ is also absolutely continuous.
Since $g$ is absolutely continuous it has derivative a.e. Clearly, if $f(x)\neq 0$ and $f$ is differentiable in $x$, we have $g’(x)=\frac{f(x)}{g(x)} f’(x)$. This here is a scalar product.
I assume that this formula holds also in general almost everywhere, where $\frac{f(x)}{g(x)}$ is supposed to be $0$ if $f(x)=0$.
My thoughts so far: Let $A:=f^{-1}(0)$. Then as I mentioned above the formula is correct for $x\notin A$. It is also correct for $x\in \mathring A$, because $f$ is constant around $x$ (this is why I wanted to set $\frac{f(x)}{g(x)}=0$ for $f(x)=0$). But this formula will not be correct for $x\in \partial A$. But if $\partial A$ is a zero-set this doesn’t matter. So I only need to prove that $\partial A$ is a zero-set. Is this true and why?

Any closed set can be written as $f^{-1}(0)$ for a smooth function $f$.  In particular,  a fat Cantor set is of this type and its boundary has positive measure.

Is your question whether $g$ is absolutely continuous or how the derivative looks like where $f=0$?

My Question is how the derivative of $g$ looks like. And to show that the formula above is correct (almost everywhere) it suffices to prove that $\partial A$ has measure $0$.
